# Can't install Wordpress plugins locally

Tags: wordpress, plugins, localhost

Any plugin I try to install on my dev site on localhost asks me to enter my FTP credentials.

What do I enter for this as I am doing it locally therefore don't have any FTP details?

It's asking for: Hostname, FTP Username & FTP Password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your wp-config.php file and place this:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```